# Change text color of TextInput in React Native Paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

How can I change text color of TextInput in React Native Paper without wrapping in PaperProvider?

Currently this works:

```js
const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    text: "orange",
  }
};

<PaperProvider theme={theme}>
  <TargetComponent />
</PaperProvider>
```

However I want to control text color through passed props from a parent component.
Strangely, passing `backgroundColor` works but `color` does not.

Removing the `PaperProvider` wrapping doesn't help either.

This is the relevant code in TargetComponent:

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        type="outlined"
        style={this.props.style}
        onChangeText={this.props.onChange}
        label={this.props.label}
        value={this.props.value || "Replace this text"}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      />
    </View>
)
```

`this.props.style` is:

```js
{
    color: "orange", // This does not work
    backgroundColor: "transparent" // This works
},
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found a solution.  But for those in the same predicament:

For some reason `color` is not recognized as a `style` prop even though others, like `backgroundColor`, are.

Simply pass `theme` as a prop to `TextInput`.  In that `theme` object, assign the text color like so:

```js
      <TextInput
        type="outlined"
        style={{ ...styles.textInput, ...this.props.style }}
        underlineColor={this.theme.colors.primary}
        onChangeText={this.props.onChange}
        label={this.props.label}
        value={this.props.value || "Replace this text"}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        theme={{ colors: { text: this.props.style.color } }}
      />
```

Updated for functional components and React Native Paper 5.x
*(also if you want label color control)*:

```js
const MyFuncComponent = ({style, colors, onChange, label, value}) => {

  const Label = <Text color={style.labelColor}>{label}</Text>;

  <TextInput
    type="outlined"
    style={{ ...styles.textInput, ...style }}
    underlineColor={theme.colors.primary}
    onChangeText={onChange}
    label={Label}
    value={value || "Replace this text"}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    textColor={style.color}
  />

}
```

Comment: What if I want to change only the label text color? any solutions for that? thx

Comment: and for disabled? Do you have to something like this for that const customTextColor =   editable === true ? 'black' : 'grey' and set that as the main text color?

Comment: @GabrielAugusto You can pass a component to label prop in <TextInput />, which means you can have your custom component and give it any styles you want.
`<TextInput label={<Text style={{color: "#someColor"}}>{someText}</Text>} />`

Answer (score 24):

```
theme={{
         colors: {
                    placeholder: 'white', text: 'white', primary: 'white',
                    underlineColor: 'transparent', background: '#003489'
            }
      }}
```

Comment: This does not satisfy - "I want to control text color through passed props".

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew did get solution by using props?. for same requirement i posted new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052170/how-can-we-send-props-to-withstyles-react-js-meterial-textfield

Please help if you fond solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line `theme={{colors: {text: 'Your Color' }}}` to the `<TextInput/>` of React native paper.

```
        <TextInput
            placeholder= {'Some Text'}
            theme={{
              colors: {
                    text: 'white',
                 }
           }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default background color of `lightTheme` for `TextInput`, you can set `surfaceVariant: "white"`.

By doing this, the background color for all TextInput components will be changed, eliminating the need to modify each one individually. I discovered this after delving layer by layer into the implementation details.

For a clearer understanding, consider going through the Theme documentation at https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/theming.

```
   const lightTheme = {
      ...MD3LightTheme,
      colors: {
        ...MD3LightTheme.colors,
        surfaceVariant: "white",
      },
      roundness: 1.5,
    };
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<TextInput
    type="outlined"
    style={this.props.style}
    onChangeText={this.props.onChange}
    label={this.props.label}
    value={this.props.value || "Replace this text"}
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
    theme={{ colors: { text: 'white' } }}
  />
```

**just add color in --- theme={{ colors: { text: 'your_color' } }}**